# Why can't TypeScript automatically assert types in this example?

Tags: typescript, typing, type-assertion

```
interface Model {
  a: string | null;
}

interface ModelA {
  a: string;
}

function myFunc(m: ModelA) {
  console.log(m.a.length);
}

function ModelFactory(): Model {
  return { a: null };
}

const model = ModelFactory();

if (model.a) {
  console.log(model.a.length);

  myFunc({a:"s"});
  myFunc(model); // Errors
}
```

TypeScript playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmEA2yDeAUMsnAFzIDOYUoA5sgD7IgCuOOA3IQL6GGhIsRCgzYcAQQLFSFarRB1ufQjFYgEYYOhDIAtgE8AYuoQAKPRTG4JASmkkEOyuhwQAdDnR0L7uJ4hFMAALW2V+NQ0tHTQsXCNEMHQoAzNbKzi8IhIoCDBWKF18WRZ2PB5wwicQan1M5ABeWPEEzWTUsP5gGGQLTL97bORqlzdPbz7xPwCg0O4ZQxMNM3xyACJKNZ5OkkXTSdxOviA).

I know I can write a user-defined typeguard or use " as ModelA" but both feel like sidestepping the type system. Any reason why it can't use the if type guard and conclude the second call to myFunc is also typesafe?